# how to use i18next in sailsjs

Tags: javascript, sails.js, i18next, i18next-http-backend

we are using handlebar to render the view and now must use `i18next` lib to render the translated pages in our `sailsjs` backend but i could not find any example on how to integrate i18next in sailsjs and use it in my template.

i am aware that there is [i18next-http-middleware](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-middleware)
but i could not get my head around how to integrate it with `sailsjs` (*very new to sailsjs*) and official docs of `i18next` also does not have any example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to make it work with [Built-in HTTP middleware](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/middleware) configuration
by adding a new middleware function in order array and initializing the `i18next` in the provided functions.

```js
// config/http.js

const i18next = require("i18next"),
  middleware = require("i18next-http-middleware"),
  i18nConfig = require("./i18n").i18n;

module.exports.http = {
  middleware: {
    order: ["i18n", "...other middlewares"],

    i18n: (function () {
      i18next.use(middleware.LanguageDetector).init(i18nConfig);

      return middleware.handle(i18next, {});
    })(),
  },
};
```